# Picture not appearing on feed dialog

Tags: feed

I'm trying to add a Facebook Feed Dialog to the bottom of an email that promotes our new course. The feed contains a jpg of our log. The image appears properly when the user clicks the button, but when it posts to their feed, the image does not appear.

Here is the syntax I'm using for the Feed Dialog:

```
<a href="
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=761322513966925
&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thegarbagemansguide.com%2Fimages%2Fgid%2FlogoGID-email.jpg
&name=Free Marketing Course - Limited Time Offer!
&description=Getting It Done is all you need to jumpstart your company's marketing. And for a limited time, you can try a full 8-week course for FREE!
&link=http://www.gettingitdone.today/free-course
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F
">
```

I've tried replacing the &picture with a standard-formatted URL:

```
[http://www.thegarbagemansguide.com/images/gid/logoGID-email.jpg][1]
```

but I get the same result: no image after the feed posts.

I tried uploading a photo of the issue but it tells me that I have too low of a reputation.

I'd welcome some help on this issue.

Many thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

That image is too small (only 90×61 pixels in size) – you need to use an image that is at least 200×200 px big.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just uploaded a new photo: http://www.thegarbagemansguide.com/images/gid/logo-200x200.jpg and tried it again. There's progress--the feed post now draws a box where the logo should be, but it's still not showing the logo itself. The image is 250x250. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think I fixed it. I changed the name of the photo to logo_facebook.jpg, thinking that the dash might be causing Facebook a problem. Sure enough, replacing the hyphen with the underscore did the trick. The logo is now showing up as it should.

Comment: _“thinking that the dash might be causing Facebook a problem”_ – hm, I doubt that. Rather more likely, that some kind of ad-blocker (in your browser) removed the image – that often happens for images that contain ”dimensions” in the filename in such a form, because advertising banner images often do that as well.

Comment: Thanks so much. I never knew that! I will make sure to avoid using dimensions in my image names from this point forward. Thank you very much for your help and assistance. I really appreciate it!